# Detecting keypresses in Windows to automate window functions in python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, keypress, minimize

I'm creating an application to automatically perform keystrokes into the same, multiple windows that are open at the same time. These windows are all child windows from a parent.

For example, there are four windows and I want to press a key that will send `CTRL-K` to them, then immediately send `WIN+M` to all of them. After some time, I want to press another key that will then send `SHIFT+WIN+M`, and then `CTRL+O`.

I'm stuck on capturing windows using [EnumWindow](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/pywin32/win32gui__EnumWindows_meth.html) and all of that. I'm familiar with callbacks, but a little confused on how to use them.

I'm also considering using [pyWinAuto](http://pywinauto.github.io/)'s SendKeys.

I do realize there are programs like [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) that can do all of this for me, but I'm learning and this would be a fun exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using PyAutoit for this, it's fairly straightforward to use and it usually works well. Steps to install the package and a simple example can be found here :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt/0.3